# from long to wide format multiple variables in R

Tags: long-format-data

I have a table in long format like this:

```
gene  tissue tpm
  A   liver   5
  A   brain   2
  B   ovary   10
  B   brain   1
  C   brain   15
  C   liver   6
```

I'd like to convert it into a wider format:

```
gene tissue1 tissue2 tpm1 tpm2
  A  liver   brain    5    2
  B  ovary   brain    10   1
  C  brain   liver    15   6
```

I have tried with `dcast` and `spread` but I get this result:

```
gene  liver brain ovary
 A      5     2     NA
 B      NA    1     10
 C      6     15    NA
```

Which is NOT what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a function that can solve this puzzle all at once in R language, but you can use a for loop to rearrange you data frame.

The code is presented below:

```
data <- data.frame(gene=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                tissue=c("liver", "brain", "ovary", "brain", "brain", "liver"),
                tpm=c(5,2,10,1,15,6))

gene.unique <- unique(data$gene)
i <- 1
for (dummy in gene.unique) {
  genes.idx <- which(data$gene == dummy)
  tissue1[i] <- data$tissue[genes.idx[1]]
  tissue2[i] <- data$tissue[genes.idx[2]]
  tpm1[i] <- data$tpm[genes.idx[1]]
  tpm2[i] <- data$tpm[genes.idx[2]]
  i <- i+1
}

data.final <- data.frame(gene=gene.unique, tissue1, tissue2, tpm1, tpm2)

  gene tissue1 tissue2 tpm1 tpm2
1    A   liver   brain    5    2
2    B   ovary   brain   10    1
3    C   brain   liver   15    6
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! It works if I first create empty vectors for each variable:
`tissue1 = vector()`
`tissue2 = vector()`
`tpm1=vector()`
`tpm2=vector()`

Comment: If my suggestion has solved your problem, mark it as accepted answer.